# null string test is always true

Tags: java, android, string, null

I already saw a lot of similar posts, but none seems to be the same as this. I am testing if a string is null in my Java Android (2.2) app and whatever the string is, it is always true. Here is the code :

```
public static String getLocalBluetoothName(){
    String name;

    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }
    try{    
        name = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
        if(name == null){
            System.out.println("Name is null!");
            name = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
        }
    return name;
    }
    catch (Exception e){            
        return "";
    }
}
```

The if(name == null) is always true even if my string has a value. By the way, I also tried mBluetoothAdapter.getName() == null and it is always true too. I saw somewhere that you can do something like that:

```
if(name.equals("null")){

}
```

But if the string is null, wouldn't that create an exception because I should not be able to use a method if the object is null? Also, testing "null" is somewhat strange to me...

Comment: "The if(name == null) is always true even if my string has a value" - I'm afraid I just don't believe that. If the value of `name` is a non-null reference, it really *won't* go into that block. I suggest you add more diagnostics to help understand what's going on.

Comment: *But if the string is `null`, wouldn't that create an exception because I should not be able to use a method if the object is `null?`* Yes, you're right. Seems that your bluetooth adapter doesn't have a name (that's why it is `null`, and yes, it is really odd).

Comment: How did you know that the variable `name` has a value? Did you see this in a debugger? did you print it out or are you guessing?

Comment: Before `if(name == null){`, add as sysout to print the name value: `System.out.println("Name is: " +name);`. This will give you idea, why it's always getting inside if block.

Comment: @Math do you have `BLUETOOTH` permission in your manifest ?

Comment: Kiruwka, yes I have the BLUETOOTH permission. Danish, I saw the value of the variable in the debugger. My device has a bluetooth name. I tried to disable bluetooth and then, the variable is null. But like I said, the if always returns true.

Comment: @Math I see. What is the actual device you running your code on ? I mean android version ?

Comment: @kiruwka The device is a Motorla Atrix phone running Android 2.3.6. My app supports Android 2.2.

Comment: @Math You can check what your device name is set to on your phone `Settings -> Wireless & Network Setting -> Bluetooth Settings` -> device Name (and make sure your bluetooth is turned on). You can try changing it there as well.

Comment: @kiruwka Thanks but I already put the device name in this option and this is the name that I see in my debugger. I tried to change it and the debugger is reflecting the change. Also, if I disable the bluetooth, the name is null (which is normal)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51456/discussion-between-kiruwka-and-math)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simplified version :

```
public static String getLocalBluetoothName(){
    String name = null;

    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (adapter == null) {
        //System.out.println("Can't get adapter");
        Log.d(TAG, "Can't get adapter");
        return name;
    }

    if ((name = adapter.getName()) == null) {
        //System.out.println("Name is null!");
        Log.d(TAG, "Name is null!");
        name = adapter.getAddress();
    }

    return name;
}
```

and don't forget to include `android.permission.BLUETOOTH` permission in your app's manifest.

Also, note that sometimes your debugger may trick you by showing executing specific branches that are not in fact run (happened to me debugging in Eclipse before). So, make sure that you ACTUALLY have `Name is null` output in logcat, otherwise your name may be not `null`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. The debugger was not branching like it should. If I remove the try catch, the debugger is behaving normally. In fact, my code was working well all this time, it is the debugger that was acting strange. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
name = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
```

Since `name` is null, your Bluetooth adapter probably doesn't have a name.

Comment: The name variable is not null. The problem is that if(name == null) returns true even if name has some text in it.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, `mBluetoothAdapter.getName()` is always returning null, that is why the if condition is always returning true. Your method of comparing `if(name == null)` is absolutely correct, no doubt in this.